# Android Ksopa2 Result

Tags: android, soap

Iam getting a result from soap webserice like this.

> Soap:
>   GetHospitalByPlaceResponse{GetHospitalByPlaceResult=anyType{Hospital=anyType{HId=1;
>   HospitalName=A J Hospital; Address=Kazhakkoottam;
>   District=Thiruvananthapuram; State=Kerala; City=Thiruvananthapuram;
>   Place=Kazhakkoottam; Pincode=695581; Phone=8547468908; };
>   Hospital=anyType{HId=2; HospitalName=Suja Hospital;
>   Address=Kazhakkoottam; District=Thiruvananthapuram; State=Kerala;
>   City=Thiruvananthapuram; Place=Kazhakkoottam; Pincode=695581;
>   Phone=9567288636; }; Hospital=anyType{HId=3; HospitalName=C S I
>   Medical Hospital; Address=Kazhakkoottam; District=Thiruvananthapuram;
>   State=Kerala; City=Thiruvananthapuram; Place=Kazhakkoottam;
>   Pincode=695581; Phone=9020210021; }; };}

I don't know how to parse this to get the hospitalName and Phone
Please can anyone help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Write a method like this;

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parseMethod(){

    SoapObject so = get_soap_object();

    String METHOD_RESULT = "SERVICENAME"+"Result";
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fullList= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> hospitalNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phoneList = new ArrayList<String>();


if (so != null) {

        try {

            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            so.getPropertyInfo(0, pi);

            String result_name = pi.getName();


            if (METHOD_RESULT.equals(result_name)) {



                SoapObject soResult = (SoapObject) so.getProperty(0);
                SoapObject soResult2 = (SoapObject) soResult.getProperty("GetHospitalByPlaceResult");

                String hospital,phone;
                if (soResult !=  null) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < soResult2.getPropertyCount(); j++){
                        SoapObject soResult3 = (SoapObject) soResult2.getProperty(j);
                        PropertyInfo pi_name = new PropertyInfo();
                        soResult2.getPropertyInfo(j, pi_name);
                        String propertyArray = pi_name.getName();
                        if(propertyArray.equals("Hospital")){

                    for(int i = 0; i < soResult3.getPropertyCount() ; i++){
                    PropertyInfo pi_sr = new PropertyInfo();
                    soResult3.getPropertyInfo(i, pi_sr);
                    String propertyName = pi_sr.getName();

                    if ("HospitalName".equals(propertyName)) {
                        hospitalName= String.valueOf(soResult3.getProperty(propertyName).toString());
                        hospitalList.add(hospitalName);
                    }
                    else if("Phone".equals(propertyName)){
                        phone = String.valueOf(soResult3.getProperty(propertyName).toString());
                        phoneList.add(phone);
                    }

                    }
                        }
                }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("exception", e.toString());
        }

    }
    fullList.add(hospital);
    fullList.add(phone);

    return fullList;
}
```